# Mouse stuck in different select mode pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I know that when one presses the scroll button down one can access many lines at once and selcet them partly but now evenmy normal mouse selects like that, with multiple cursors:
[image]

I have no idea how to escape. pls help :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the background, and unselect "Column Selection Mode":

[image]

Or use the shortcut keys to toggle the mode:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>